# First time using PHP and I can't get echo or print to work

Tags: php

I have a fairly straightforward piece of code

```
<div id="questdiv">
    <?php
        $a = rand() % 100;
        $b = rand() % 100;
        print "What is ";
        print (string)$a;
        print " + ";
        print (string)$b;
        print "?";
    ?>
</div>
```

and yet the text that appears in my div is

```
What is "; print (string)$a; print " + "; print (string)$b; print "?
"; ?>
```

What have I done wrong? I tried replacing `print` with `echo` and that did the same thing.

Comment: Does the filename end in `.php`? Is the code on a computer with a web server (Apache, IIS, etc.)?

Comment: your php didn't interpreted... check you properly install it

Comment: Is PHP installed?  That code works fine.

Comment: It looks like you're not running it on a server that executes PHP.

Comment: I just made the file in Notepad++, saved it with the extension .php, and ran it in Google Chrome.

Comment: You can just open a PHP file in a browser and expect it to work. PHP is a server-side language that needs to run on a server.

Comment: @user3482256 check my answer out please! you need a server for your PHP to work.

Comment: I thought my computer WAS a server lol. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDxaRfwzFrs and the guy makes it seem like the terms are interchangeable.

Comment: You can install a server on your PC, but by default your PC has no server setup to run PHP.

Comment: Put my answer as accepted, if it helped you though. So other people can utilize our thread when they have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is obviously not saved as .php file.

Probably your file is called something like this:

```
index.html
index.htm
```

change it into

```
xxx.php
```

Aswell you need a Server for your PHP, to work.

Check following website, to setup your own local server and make your PHP work:
https://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
<div id="questdiv">
<?php
    $a = rand(0,100);
    $b = rand(0,100);
 echo "what is ".$a." + ".$b."?";
?>
</div>
```

And check if extension is .php (file) + if server supports PHP

Btw this is the short version of your code so try using this way ;)

Comment: Wrong answer -> this code is working fine. Its probably an error with his local server(if he has one) which is not interpreting php, or the file ending is NOT .php

Comment: @Xatenev but you have to admit this code is shorter(and correct) where there can be made less mistakes if he learns doing it this way it will only bring him advantages, no ?

Comment: Sure, but thats not his problem, specified in this thread. You can add those answers, but specify them as just a help, and not as answer on his problem